# android: how to set visibility on my textview with using arraylist value

Tags: android, arraylist

I use arraylist to show/hide visibility of 3 textview, when i check array list for change visibility its work only one text view at same time, means if condition of 3 textview be true then 3 textview must be visible toghere, but its show me only one text view  , how I can get it ? thank for ur help.

its my code :

```
public class Favorites_page extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String on="on",off="off";
static TextView tv_fav1,tv_fav2,tv_fav3,tv_fav4,tv_fav5,tv_fav6,tv_fav7,tv_favoritetittle;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorites);

    boolean check = list.isEmpty();
    if(check){
    list.add(0,off);list.add(1,off);list.add(2,off);
        save();
         }

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    int score = pref.getInt("score", 0);
    //
    tv_fav1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav1);
    tv_fav2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav2);
    tv_fav3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav3);
    tv_fav4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav4);
    tv_fav5= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav5);
    tv_fav6= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav6);
    tv_fav7= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fav7);
    tv_favoritetittle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_favoritetittle);

    tv_fav1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav2.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav3.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav4.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav5.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav6.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_fav7.setOnClickListener(this);


    switch (score) {

    case 99:
        if(score == 99){

            tv_favoritetittle.setText("Nothing");

        }
        break;

    case 100:
        if(score == 100){
        list.set(0,on);
        save();
        }
        break;
case 101:
    if(score == 101){
        list.set(1,on);
        save();
    }
        break;
case 102:
    if(score == 102){
        list.set(2,on);
        save(); 
    }
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }

//// the problem is here... with this command only textview is visible

    if (list.get(0)==on) {
        tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (list.get(1)==on) {
        tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (list.get(2)==on) {
        tv_fav5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        tv_fav5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


 } // marbot be Content 

public void save()
{
    Bundle value= new Bundle();
    value.putStringArrayList("temp1", list);      
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}  // marbot be Activity
```

also i add this code to my cods , but its not work too

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            if(list.get(0)==on){
            tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
            }

        case 1:
            if(list.get(1)==on){
            tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
            }

        case 2:
            if(list.get(2)==on){
            tv_fav5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
            }


        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? ` if condition of 3 textview be true then 3 textview must be visible toghere,`

Comment: no only one textview will be show even 3 condtion is true,

Comment: 3 condition or 3rd condition? can you say which condition ? `if(score == 101){`? and what is the actual flow? like if the score is == something, it should do this.

Comment: 3 condition , i want if condtion 1 is true a textview 1 be visible , i want if condtion 2 is true a textview 2be visible , i want if condtion3 is true a textview 3be visible and finaly every 3 texview be visible

Comment: Check my answer below. how come finally all textview will be visible when you are getting only one value from sharedPreference?

Comment: yes i pass only one value , u mean i must pass all value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is, why only one `TextView` is Visible and why not others?

It's because you are getting only one value from `sharedPreferences` & saving it in `score` variable and when it goes to `switch()`, it goes to only one case if that is true.

Suppose if you are getting `score` 100 from `sharedPrefences`,

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
int score = pref.getInt("score", 0); // now score value is 100
```

then it goes to `switch()` block and will do the operation only in this part

```
 case 100:
    if(score == 100){
      list.set(0,on);
      save();
    }
```

So, when it comes down to check this if condition,

```
 if (list.get(0)==on) {
        tv_fav7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

this returns true & tvfav7 visibility will be Visible.

But, when it goes to next if condition block,

```
 if (list.get(1)==on) {
        tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        tv_fav6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

this will fail because in `switch` block, it doesn't go to the below case to set second position and third position to `on`.

```
case 101:
    if(score == 101){
        list.set(1,on);
        save();
    }
        break;
case 102:
    if(score == 102){
        list.set(2,on);
        save(); 
    }
    break;
```

as the score is not 101 or 102. It's **100**. So, just remember in **switch** block, only one case will be executed if it's true and not entire thing.

Comment: thanks, however my be 102 be  score with user choice later, but its now show textview

Comment: If the score is 102, then you need to do the same operation again to reflect the change. Have a separate method that do this stuff. But, remember when the score is 102, it won't go to 101 and 100 case in switch block that means 101 and 100 is off, so it goes to else statement in your if and else condition and set the two textView as invisibile and 3rd textview will be only visible **based on your logic**. You need to change your logic if you want all TextView to be visible.

Comment: u mesn i must pass all my data with shareprefrence?

Comment: @farzad226 can you say what are you trying to achieve? I'll tell the logic.

Comment: this is favorites page , when user clicked on favorites icon on another activity i transfer a value as score and pass to this activity, i want all topic that user mark as favorites will be showed in this activity, thas's it

Comment: In that activity have a arrayList and put all the clicked values to it and save this arrayList in sharedPreference. For ex, assume u are saving pepsi, coke, lime. In favorite page, get that arrayList. Have a if else condition, if coke is present display only one textview, if coke, lime, pepsi present display 3 textview. If coke and pepsi, display only 2 textview. You got it?

Comment: i dont think it good , because when then values be more than 50 i cant wrote if condition for 50 item or mybe one of this value changed !!! no another way?